# ASP.NET Editing a GridView row

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

3 Dropdownlists in same row when I edit.

When 1 dropdownlist has a selection, the other 2 should go to index of 0 (the empty one).

Example of my code:

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project" SortExpression="Project">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%#Eval("Project") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ProjectDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ProjectDropDownList_Changed" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                            DataSourceID="ProjectDataSource" DataTextField="navn" DataValueField="navn">
                            <asp:ListItem>-- choose one --</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

My SelectionChanged even handler:

```
protected void ProjektDropDownList_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList project = (DropDownList) GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex].FindControl("ProjectDropDownList");
            DropDownList kunde = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex].FindControl("KundeDropDownList");
            DropDownList øvrige = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex].FindControl("ØvrigeDropDownList");

            if(project.SelectedIndex >= 0 && kunde != null && øvrige != null) {
                kunde.SelectedIndex = 0;
                øvrige.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }

        }
```

I get a nullpointer when trying to fetch other controls in the same row... How do I fix this?

Comment: Nullpointer for which object?

Comment: Nullpointer for the DropDownList's i'm trying to reach outside of the UpdatingEvent/EditingEvent's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it's the SelectedIndex that you're looking for. Isn't there an EditItemIndex which you should be using?

Comment: Simply enough that worked! Looks like this: `DropDownList project = (DropDownList) GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex].FindControl("ProjectDropDownList");`